# Temporarily capturing logging output via stderr

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging

I have a bunch of unittests, for one of them I want to capture what logging outputs into a variable (meaning it should not be visible to the guy running the tests). Before I start thinking about doing that I've been trying to get a simple test case to work:

```
import logging
import sys
from cStringIO import StringIO


logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Abc():

    @staticmethod
    def pr():
        logger.setLevel("WARN")

        old_stderr = sys.stderr 
        sys.stderr = mystderr = StringIO()
        logger.warn('bla bla bla')
        sys.stderr = old_stderr
        print mystderr.getvalue()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Abc.pr()
```

But this doesn't. It outputs:

```
WARNING:__main__:bla bla bla
(empty line from print)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.stderr` is a pointer to the object. So first call to `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)` will set logger's stream to the valid stream.

Later change to `sys.stderr` will only change what `sys.stderr` points to, but not the stream inside the logger.

I suggest the following:

```
@staticmethod
def pr():
    logger.setLevel("WARN")

    mystderr = StringIO()
    logging.basicConfig(stream=mystderr)
    logger.warn('bla bla bla')
    print 'my [ {} ]'.format(mystderr.getvalue())
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't realize that. And on top of that I wouldn't even have known had I done it correctly because the output woud look identical. Thanks!